Why is my profile picture not displayed correctly?
I have had the same profile picture network-wide since 2008.

Until recently, the same profile picture was used for all SE sites including bricks.SE. Today when I visited bricks.SE, I noticed that my custom profile picture has been replaced with a generic one.

My profile picture appears correctly in all the other SE sites I've visited today. Did someone break something here, or has my profile picture been deemed unsuitable--for this site only--because it depicts a LEGO™ minifig?

It looks like this change happened back in February 2020 - is it possible that the change is longer-standing than you think but you didn't notice? It look like the change coincided with the email used for the account changing.

I don't understand why it's only for this SE site and not others. I use the same login cookie for all.
